# Django translation.activate doesn't work when redirect

Tags: django, redirect

I have a two-language Django website and when I want to change the language, it doesn't work.

Here is the links in the template to change the language:

```
<a href="{% url 'change_lang' %}?lang=en&next={{ request.path }}">EN</a>
<a href="{% url 'change_lang' %}?lang=fa&next={{ request.path }}">FA</a>
```

As you can see, I send the language that I want and the current path as parameters for the view.

This is the urls.py:

```
from .views import change_language

urlpatterns = [
    path('change_lang', change_language, name='change_lang'),
]
```

And this is the views.py:

```
from django.utils.translation import activate

def home(request):
    # My commands

    # activate('fa')

    context = {
        # Some key and values
    }
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)


def change_language(request):
    activate(request.GET.get('lang'))
    return redirect(request.GET.get('next'))
```

And I've added these two line in the settings.py as well:

```
LANGUAGES = [
    ('fa', 'Persian'),
    ('en', 'English'),
]
```

And I found that `activate(request.GET.get('lang'))` doesn't work.

But when I uncomment the `activate('fa')` in the `home` view, It does work. But this command doesn't work in the `change_language` method.

> I've found that it is because of the `redirect` method. I replace the `redirect` with `render` and then the activate works!

How can I do activate a language and then redirect?

Thanks for your help.